# single signon (OpenID, OAuth, etc.) with Java applet?

Tags: oauth, applet, openid, single-sign-on

In our [system](http://www.fencing-game.de/en/lobby), we are now using an architecture with a Java applet client (embedded in dumb HTML pages) and a Java server, communicating by sockets (over SSL).

Users have to login into the system using a username and password (hopefully not shared) - the password is then stored in hashed form in our database.

Recently having read Jeff's [Your Internet Driver's License](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/your-internet-drivers-license.html), I think about allowing our users to login with alternative mechanisms, like OpenID, so they don't have to remember username and password, but we still know the user is the same one that logged in one day before from another computer.

As far as I understand, OpenID works by using browser redirects combined with some server-side cryptography. This looks like complicated (if not impossible) to combine with our applet (or applet combined with non-HTTP server, really), which should allow the login here.

OAuth either uses a similar mechanism, or some token provided to the user, which the user then would input into my applet. The applet would have to store this token at the client (per JNLP PersistenceService or similar) to allow a repeated login, but this would mean for every computer to obtain a new token, not easily allow multiple users share a computer (account), and not very much simplify login.

Are there other ways which could be used here to enable a single sign-on system here, or is this simply impossible without at least getting some HTTP-server-side code to transfer the credentials to our applet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenId to log in your users, outside the applet, using one of the [OpenId libraries](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries). It would be the normal flow, including server-side processes and the redirection of the user to the OpenId provider's page. Then you pass the user Id to the applet:

```
<object codetype="application/java" ...>
    <param name="user" value="myOpenId">
</object>
```

Then you can authenticate an user using `this.getParameter("user")`.

Comment: This in fact lets anyone in with any OpenID (you only need to modify the HTML code locally), if I understand right. I don't think this is a secure implementation. This would need at least some signature from my web server confirming to the applet (and its server) that the OpenID authentification was successful.

Comment: You're right, you can encode the parameter, or pass a key generated by your server and pointing to the user.